# Why here I have this output when I use the let keyword which is blocked scope?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have this code

```
function greetPerson(name: string) {
  let greet;
  if (name === "john") {
    let greet = "hello john";
  } else {
    let greet = "hi there";
  }
  console.log(greet);

}

greetPerson("john");
```

when I have this three declaration, they should be three different in each scope. Why do I get `hello john` as the output?

Comment: Your output: `undefined`

Comment: 1. not JavaScript with the `name: string` 2. nope

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring same variable in every condition

```js
function greetPerson(name: string) { 
    let greet;
    if(name === "john") {
         let greet = "hello john";
    } else {
         let greet = "hi there";
    }
    console.log(greet);
    
}

greetPerson("john");
```

change it like this:

```js
function greetPerson(name: string) { 
    let greet;
    if(name === "john") {
        greet = "hello john";
    } else {
        greet = "hi there";
    }
    console.log(greet);
    
}

greetPerson("john");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can refractoring your code. Your fuction output: undefined.
My solution and its work:

```js
function greetPerson(name) { 
    if(name === "john") {
         return "hello john"
    } else {
         return "hi there"
    }
}

display.log(greetPerson("john"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing 2 mistakes here.

1. inside function call pass just the name(No need to mention it's type)
2. declaring greet first time is enough. you're declaring it again inside if-else.

```js
function greetPerson(name) { 
    let greetn= '';
    if(name === "john") {
         greet = "hello john";
    } else {
         greet = "hi there";
    }
    console.log(greet);
    
}

greetPerson("john");
```